# python selenim - element.text returns empty string when has multiple lines

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm using chrome webderiver and `some_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='info']/div[@class='componentsText'])")` to find html element and it has text with multiple blank lines before and after the required text.
When I'm using `some_element.text`, it returns an empty string.

html element content example:

```
                                                                    aaa bbb, ccc ddd, fff.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the multiple blank lines before and after the desired text you can use the `strip()` method.

---

### `strip()`

The [strip()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_strip.htm) method returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string (default whitespace characters).

---

### Solution

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='info']/div[@class='componentsText'])").text.strip())
```